# Is there a platform-independent method for opening links in an Outlook-addin?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have an outlook-addin written in Angular framework, which communicates with the Outlook through the office-js.

My goal is to implement a service that opens any kind of URLs/links in any mainstream platforms where outlook is available, to be specific: in Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer, The MacOS desktop Outlook - old and new versions either, and most of the Windows desktop Outlook versions (2016, 2019, O365). But unfortunately I can not find a way that works in all of the platforms, and I want to avoid implementing it in a platform-dependent manner.

The first problem I encountered with, is that when I am trying to open links by a simple js function `window.open(url)` then the outlook versions that use Internet Explorer as an engine are failing to open URLs that contain the character #. That is because IE does not seem to be able to read this character and it cuts the URL in half by the # character and it completely removes the parts followed by the #.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Antrim#/media/File:Ballycastle_Harbour_-_geograph.org.uk_-_468327.jpg

```
window.open(
  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Antrim#/media/File:Ballycastle_Harbour_-_geograph.org.uk_-_468327.jpg",
  "_blank"
);
```

For example, if I try to open the URL above on Windows outlook 2019 which uses Internet Explorer as it's engine, then the url will look like this in the end:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Antrim

For a solution I've implemented a workaround that encodes the URL by a built-in function that comes with typescript which allows the IE to be able to open the link. By simply passing the encoded URL to the `window.open()` does not work because it concatenates the url with the host of my addin, which results in an invalid link.

```
window.open(
  encodeURIComponent(
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Antrim#/media/File:Ballycastle_Harbour_-_geograph.org.uk_-_468327.jpg"
  ),
  "_blank"
);
```

The host of my addin + the encoded URL:

> https://localhost.eu.ngrok.io/https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCounty_Antrim%23%2Fmedia%2FFile%3ABallycastle_Harbour_-_geograph.org.uk_-_468327.jpg

So I had to redirect manually with a simple html code as shown below:

redirect.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function (event) {
            var regex = /\?url=(.*)/ig;
            var match = regex.exec(location.search);
            if (match && match[1] && match[1] !== "") {
                location.href = decodeURIComponent(match[1]);
            }
            else {
                document.body.innerHTML = "Redirect failed!";
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

typescript code:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Antrim#/media/File:Ballycastle_Harbour_-_geograph.org.uk_-_468327.jpg"
window.open("./redirect.html?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url), "_blank");
```

Unfortunately, this method also has some flaws in the desktop outlook of MacOS. Redirecting makes the links open in a simple webviewer of the outlook application, and not in Safari as it is expected since the default browser is set to Safari in both of the system preferences and in the outlook browser preference. Despite the fact that it can open the links in this webviewer, I can not use it, because some of the webpages I want to navigate to does not support to be opened by the webviewer.

I was suspecting that this behaviour is caused by the relativity of the url ("./redirect..."). So I have tried building the URL by adding dynamically or even hardcoding the host of my addin to the beginning of the URL this way:

```
`${window.location.origin + window.location.pathname}/redirect.html?url=` + encodeURIComponent(url);
```

But there was no difference in the results by doing it, so I am guessing that referencing the host of the addin itself does not change quality or state of the URL, meaning that it is still managed as a relative link.

Since I had the opportunity to host the redirect.html from another server, I have tried referencing the redirect.html file from another host, and that way even the MacOS Outlook worked perfectly, proving my suspicion of the wrong management of relative links.

I have also tried using the function called openBrowserWindow provided by office-js the following way:

```
Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(url);
```

But this was also a dead-end, since this could neither handle the # character in IE nor it was supported in all of the platforms I need to use.

The last workaround I have tried is by completely reworking the service and instead of opening the links by using js or ts functions, I have tried binding the urls to the href attribute of `<a></a>` elements, however the application requirements exclude this method, as there are some links that are expected to be opened by double clicking, which can not be done with using an `<a>` tag as far as I know, at least not in an "hacky" way.

Which I would really like to know, what makes the links open in the webviewer of the MacOS outlook application instead of the default browser of the system? Is it a setting I am missing, or is there a way to force using the safari?

Comment: The recommended way is to use Open Browser Window API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/open-browser-window-api-requirement-sets). This will open the link in the default browser for the platform.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately  as I mentioned it is not supported in browsers, and it also can not handle the # character properly on the 2019 office outlook which uses Internet explorer as its browser engine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply doing:

```
if (Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow) {
    Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow("https://google.com");
 } else
 {
   window.open("https://google.com");
 }
```

Since openBrowserWindow is selectively not supported in OWA, window.open will automatically take over.